# Add entity to Symfony2 SonataAdminBundle dashboard

Tags: php, symfony, administration

I'm trying to integrate [SonataAdminBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle) for my Symfony2 project. I extended FOSUserBundle for security and now trying to add users administration.

I installed SonataAdminBundle, set it up (http://symfony2.local/admin/dashboard path works, using `sonata.admin.security.handler.noop` with the Symfony2 firewall), created UserAdmin class based on [SonataUserBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle) but nothing appears on dashboard page.

Service configuration is:

```
# src/G/UserBundle/Resources/config/service.yml
services:
    g.user.form.type.security_roles:
        class: G\UserBundle\Form\Type\SecurityRolesType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: sonata_security_roles}
        arguments: [Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Pool]

    g.user.admin.user:
        class: G\UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: user, label: user }
        arguments: [null, G\UserBundle\Entity\User, GUserBundle:UserAdmin]
```

I tried getting information from console using `php app/console sonata:admin:explain g.user.admin.user` - displays all information about administration with the only warning:

```
Getters constraints
   no getter constraints defined !!
```

So my question is: what could I miss so information about Entity is not appearing on admin dashboard page?

Comment: Good question. I ran into the same issue. Hopefully someone knows the answer :-)

Comment: Solved by adding the following code:

`# app/config/config.yml
sonata_admin:
    dashboard_groups:
        users:
            label: Users
            items: [g.user.admin.user]`

Comment: Post your comment as an answer & accept it. Like that, the others will see the post solved. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by adding the following code:

```
# app/config/config.yml
sonata_admin:
    dashboard_groups:
        users:
            label: Users
            items: [g.user.admin.user]
```